# Change terminal behavior for autocomplete

Tags: c, terminal, autocomplete

In the terminal for my autocomplete implementation, the commands are displaying after pressing the `ENTER`.But I want to change the terminal behavior such that the commands will be displayed without pressing enter.

My question is how to change the terminal settings for displaying the commands when I press `TAB` without pressing `ENTER`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an OS-specific way to control the terminal, like the [Console API for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/).

There are also cross-platform libraries that you can use as well, like the [ncurses library](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Read also about [Terminal capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_capabilities) for more information.